# Gitlab add default post-update

Tags: git, gitolite, hook, gitlab

we've setup Gitlab (as was described at official site). All works fine.

Now we need to add git hook to new-created projects called post-update (lets say it is located at /home/git/gitolite/hook/post-update).

I think there is some easy way to use something like skeleton to copy that file to new-created projects.

Is there any config or doc how to do that?